# WebBrowser keep url/uri encoded dont decode

Tags: c#, url, encoding, browser, uri

I have a web-browser in a win form application and I am experiencing issues when opening a URL.

The URL I pass in as a new `URL` instance is encoded with:

> / as %2f , ? as %3f and the
>   = as %3d

But when I debug my code I can see that the absolute `URL` or any of the other ones in the `webbrowser.url.*` is decoded as **/** , **?** and **=**.

How do I keep the `URL` encoded? The `URL` will not work if It is not encoded like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, when you have a `URL` that looks something like this:

> domain.com/action/doaction/?identity=12354698789

And you want it encoded like this:

> domain.com/logon?returnurl=action%2fdoaction%2f%3fidentity%3d12354698789

That does not work in your web browser. It decodes it to the first url.

I needed the `id` in the `doaction` controller so I used this code:

```
string orgId = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
```

It returns that url, if unsure, debug and trace through, you will find the right key and value.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it a problem?

If you want the undecoded URL, use the [HttpRequest.RawUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx). The query string is automatically decoded by default and there is no public parameter that would turn it off.

Comment: Well the thing is i wanted it encoded because it has to call a url with encoded path found a solution to my problem tho, will post shortly

Comment: @Croconoster: Well, I have already given you a solution (use RawUrl) :)